# Rails 4: Render partial in div after submit button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, submit, partial

I'm not getting it. I'm building a rails application and want to do some single page actions. What I got from now is, when a I pick a 'customer' from the list on the customers/index.html.erb, I render it in the 'current_customer' div. When I click on edit, the form is rendered in the 'current_customer' - perfect. But when I click on sumbit on the form, I get an error (which I understand) 'ActionController::UnknownFormat' because of the action oin the controller for 'show'. I'm routed to 'http://localhost:3000/customers/2'
What I want to is to route to 'http://localhost:3000/customers' after clikcing sumit and the render the cutomers/_show.html.erb in the 'current_customer' div.

My Code:
customers/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing Customers</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= customer.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', customer, remote: true %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_path(customer), remote: true %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', customer, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>

  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<div id="current_customer"></div>
<br>

<%= link_to 'New Customer', new_customer_path, class: "button", id: "new_customer" %>
```

customers/_show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @customer.name %>
  <%= @customer.id %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit Customer', edit_customer_path(@customer) %> |
```

customers/_edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editing Customer</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @customer %> |
```

customers/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
  <% if @customer.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@customer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this customer from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit id: "customer_button", remote: true %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

customers/edit.js.erb

```
$("#current_customer").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'customers/edit', locals: { customer: @customer } ) %>");
```

customers_controller.rb (partly)

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render layout: false}
    end
  end

  # GET /customers/new
  def new
  end

  # GET /customers/1/edit
  def edit
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render layout: false}
    end
  end

def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.update(customer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I'd be glad for every help!
Thanks

Comment: Obviously, you need to use AJAX.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ActionController::UnknownFormat in CustomersController#show -  app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:12:in `show'

Comment: You have update action right?

Comment: yes (see edit in code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `remote: true` in `form_for` tag instead of `submit` button, add it here

```
<%= form_for @customer, remote: true do |f| %>
```

Remove it from

```
<%= f.submit id: "customer_button" %>
```

Also, `update` action should accept AJAX requests too, create `update.js.erb` template and handle the AJAX request as you are submitting the form using `remote: true`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Submitting you form as is will call `POST /customer/1`. You need to defined an update method in your controller and routes, and add `method: :patch` to your form to achieve a `PATCH /customer/1`.

Also, you might want to defined a `update.js.erb` and add `remote: true` to your form to add some dynamic AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace your show link by this:

```
<%= link_to "show", {:action => :show}, :remote => true %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "show", customer_path(customer), :remote => true %>
```